# Using Roles from Azure or Microsoft Identity for Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm coding my first asp.net core 7 web app. I'm using Azure AD to authenticate users and it is working well. Now I need to create roles and assign users to theses roles for authorization. Based on different roles, users will see different things after they log in to web app.

If I create roles and assign users using Microsoft Identity, web app admin can create users and assign them to roles on their own.

But if I use the roles created in Azure then we will have to depend on Azure admin which could be inconvenient.

What is my best and easier option to implement authorization?

Secondly, I was unable to find a sample or tutorial on how to use roles created in Azure for authorization in Asp.Net Core 6 or 7. Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details. Are the roles you are talking about specific to your application? What do you mean by roles created using Microsoft Identity and roles created in Azure?

Comment: Yes, the roles will be specific to my application. And only Azure AD will be used for authentication. MS Identity Core Roles meaning creating roles in application and storing them in application database like this https://procodeguide.com/programming/aspnet-core-identity-roles-authorization/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this and every step forward depends on what your design/requirement is. If you know for certain that you will not add any other authorisation provider then you could - for the sake of centralised management - put everything in Azure.

But if, let's say, you want to add Google/Facebook/Discord authentication as well, then you should do authorisation in the application itself.

Comment: In foreseeable future, Azure AD will be used for authentication and not any other provider like Google/Facebook/Discord.

Comment: Well, then as said, put it all in AAD. Better for centralised identity management.